# Google recaptcha is not validating properly on local host

Tags: javascript, php, python, jquery

I am trying to validate Google recaptcha on local host . But it is not working properly?
How can I validate the Google reCAPTCHA on local host? What is the best solution?

Answer (score 1):

Using these keys below, you can do your tests on localhost :

**Site key**: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI

**Secret key**: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe

Google add a message on recaptcha to prevent users and the administrator that keys are just for tests.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha-v2-what-should-i-do

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just had to register my local DNS in the Key Settings, Domains, so that it was possible to validate, you need to give more details of your problem, I'm not sure exactly what validation problem is happening

Google has a faq on the subject, maybe it's interesting
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display